# how to change flutter default copy/pause/select menu of textfield?

Tags: android, flutter

When I use textfield, longpress input text can display the copy/pause/select menu, but if my mobile system's text is large, the menu will overflow screen, so whether I can change this menu or other method?

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36547
This websit is this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is the bug in Flutter itself. They going to fix it in future releases. For now you should change

child: Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: items), 
in flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_selection.dart on line 61 with

child: ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children: items,
        ),
More details you can find on Flutter github